# How to place a textview to the right of image view in android using java code?

Tags: android

I have a image view  and a text view.The text view is coming below image view.I need the textview to the right of image view.How to do it?

```
               LinearLayout ThelayoutL = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        ThelayoutL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);   

             ImageView TheItemImageL = new ImageView(mContextL);
        TheItemImageL.setImageBitmap(ItemImageBytesListG.get(PositionP));
        TheItemImageL.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        TheItemImageL.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(100, 100));

        TextView tvItemNameL = new TextView(mContextL);
        tvItemNameL.setText(zItemNameListG.get(PositionP));
        tvItemNameL.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tvItemNameL.setTextSize(10);
        tvItemNameL.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

Comment: useless question I wont down vote it but please do search before you post your questions

Answer (score 1):

try `ThelayoutL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
ThelayoutL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

to

```
ThelayoutL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```

hope it helps.